# how can i create a button in windows form which when clicked asks for two values to be entered

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to develop an application that counts number of sheep in an image

I have to add a button to a form which when clicked asks for two values to be entered by the user

I have to design a form that loads image from pc and count number of sheep in an image. The coding should be done in C#

Comment: This is too broad, please add some specific details like what you have tried so far.

Comment: A button can never ask anything, it can only be clicked

Comment: Add an event to button click. In the event, spawn another form to ask for input.

Comment: "Add an event to button click. In the event, spawn another form to ask for input." Thats what I am specifically asking for now. Can you guide mehow to do this as I am a beginner , I need to be taught step by step please.

Comment: I am looking for a code that asks for two values to e entered upon clicking a button in a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a second form to your project:

[image]

from here you can add a button on your main from, in this example Form1.

[image]

On this button a click event:

[image]

and in this method you can use the below to call your second form:

```
    private void CallForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
        secondForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

And for what you are wanting you may want to add two text box's to your second from where the user can add the required value.